# Help + in + v-ing or Help + on + v-ing?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Help + in + v-ing or Help + on + v-ing?

Example:

> I used to help my friends **in** coding C++

or

> I used to help my friends **on** coding C++

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *on* doesn't work. *In* won't seem too strange, but it doesn't seem natural. *With* could work better.

Using the simple present rather than the progressive of the verb would seem more natural to me, without needing any preposition:

> "I used to help my friends code C++"

I'm not 100% sure about generalising this, though. Certainly different verbs in the place of *coding* would work better with 'in' than in your example. I'm struggling to think of any where 'on' would work at all, but I hesitate to say there are none just because I can't think of any.

Comment: I like this answer. I think "I used to help my friends code *in* C++" also sounds correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear SamBC. I also read and remember that "Help" can't be followed by an -ing verb.